# How to get Round based scores from google play leaderboard service?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I am new to google game play leader-board service. I am creating a Round based gamed where each round last for 2 minutes. All the players globally are playing same round simultaneously. At the end of each round I submit scores to the google play leader-board service. Now how can I get highest scorer among all the players who played that particular round? I want to show leaderboard for that particular round.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Play Game Services leaderboards need to be defined before publishing the application, so for only 1 day of gaming, you would need 1800 leaderboards, and then you would need to use the management API to reset the leaderboards every day.  I don't think it is a good fit for your requirements.

Have you looked into using Firebase?  https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html

You can still use GPGS for achievements, events and quests, and even leaderboards for the daily, weekly, and all-time scores.